# How to type an inline chi in Latex

Tags: symbols

`\( \chi \)` produces a letter that is slightly below the row, but I've seen in many papers a chi that is in the same line as the rest of the row)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). You can use `\newcommand*{\MyChi}{\raisebox{0.35ex}{\( \chi \)}}%` with the `graphicx` package included in the preamble.

Comment: Do you mean `\mathcal{X}`?

Comment: \mathcal{X} is not what I mean (it's just capital X). Thank you Peter! That is it!

Comment: that is a question of font design. `\chi`is a lowercase character and its top is on the same height as of other lowercase characters. And, of course, we have an uppercase `\Chi`, which should have another height than the lowercase one. This is the reason why `\chi` has a depth.

Comment: @PeterGrill `\raisebox` *doesn't* need `graphicx`; with `\depth` instead of an eye computed `0.35ex` you get the exact depth.

Comment: Why would you want that? If you are going to write that glyph to be a chi, then you will be writing it bad (it's like writing the lowercase letter `g` with no depth, it's wrong). IMO.

Comment: @Herbert where do you get an uppercase `\Chi`? It doesn't seem to be present by default (presumably because it's identical to X.)

Comment: @Kundor: I meant `\def\Chi{X}`

Comment: I'll give a reason for wanting the raised form, as I'm writing textbooks using `$\chi$` and it has been driving me nuts for some time. This is a common symbol used for reactances in physics-style electronics. That is: `\[ \chi_L = \omega L \qquad \chi_C = \frac{1}{\omega C} \]` The way it is now, it is difficult to tell that `$\chi_L$` is even a subscripted quantity -- it can easily be mistaken for a product. As a symbol in a math expression (as opposed to an actual Greek text) its height in an equation written is *always* going to be aligned with the other symbols so that it is easy to read.

Answer (score 42):

I'm not sure why you'd want this. However, it's easy to provide it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\rchi}{{\mathpalette\irchi\relax}}
\newcommand{\irchi}[2]{\raisebox{\depth}{$#1\chi$}} % inner command, used by \rchi

\begin{document}

dg $\chi$ dg $\rchi$ dg

$\chi_\chi$ $\rchi_\rchi$

\end{document}
```

Left the normal chi, right the raised one. I added the baseline in the image just for clarity.

[image]

With `\DeclareRobustCommand`, `\rchi` can be used also in section titles (but always in math mode, so `\section{... $\rchi$ ...}`).

Comment: Hi, your method doesn't seem to look if I were to do this: `\section{\rchi}`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @yanbo `\section{$\protect\rchi$}`; or use `\DeclareRobustCommand{\rchi}{...}` instead of `\newcommand{\rchi}{...}`. I'll edit the code.

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks! As for a use, I am using it to write the characteristic function of the rationals in my real analysis homework.